# How do I change the angle of the window in Haxe?

Tags: window, haxe, haxeflixel

I wanted to try doing some stuff with the game window.
But I don't know a variable represents that the window's angle.
So yeah, does anyone know?

Comment: You mean screen orientation? That's under control of the OS.

Comment: @IlirLiburn No, I mean just the game window. Not the entire screen.

Comment: Try FlxFrame. angle https://api.haxeflixel.com/flixel/graphics/frames/FlxFrame.html